# linkGenerator.GetUriByAction not using custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a controller with 2 actions. Both have a custom route. But when I use the linkgenerator to generate those routes, it doesn't use the custom route for the second one. [Surfing to this route in my browser does work though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3MXX.png).

[As you can see in the image here, the url3 variable created by linkGenerator is not the correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wMpB.png)

Comment: I suggest you could share your route config and your asp.net core version, then we could find out the reason why it doesn't generate the right url.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.